# CyclicBarrier vs CountDownLatch for synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

I have read Bloch's Item 69(Effective Java) and there was an example of Simple framework for timing execution which uses 3 `CountDownLatch` for synchronization threads. Also Bloch says that this example can be rewritten using 1 `CyclicBarrier`. I have tried to do this and get the next code:

```
     public static long time(ExecutorService exec, int count) throws InterruptedException, BrokenBarrierException {
            CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(count+1);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                exec.submit(new Worker(cyclicBarrier, i));
            }
            System.out.println("Start processing");
            cyclicBarrier.await();
            long time = System.nanoTime();
            cyclicBarrier.await();
            long elapsedTime = (System.nanoTime() - time)/1000;
            System.out.println("FIN. ");
            return elapsedTime;

        }
private static class Worker implements Runnable {

        final CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;
        int workerNumber;

        Worker(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier, int workerCount) {
            this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
            this.workerNumber = workerCount;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                cyclicBarrier.await();
                work();
                cyclicBarrier.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private void work() {
            System.out.println("Worker " + workerNumber + " starts his job");
            System.out.println("Worker " + workerNumber + " finishes his job");
        }

    }
```

But I think there is a problem here(in `time` method): after first `await` I try to measure time of start of threads' execution, so I want to measure this time BEFORE all another threads starts. There is no any guarantee that this(`long time = System.nanoTime();`) instruction will execute before another threads start.

How can I achieve such functionality with CyclicBarrier? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CyclicBarrier` allows you to define a barrier action to be executed after all threads reached the barrier but before they resumed execution. Use `CyclicBarrier(int, Runnable)` to define it.

Obviously, in your case it's up to you to distinguish between executions of barrier action before doing work and after finishing it, something like this:

```
class TimingAction implements Runnable {
    private boolean running;
    private long start;
    private long elapsed;

    public void run() {
        if (running) {
            elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
            running = false;
        } else {
            start = System.nanoTime();
            running = true;
        }
    }
    ...
}

TimingAction timer = new TimingAction();
CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(count + 1, timer);
...
long elapsed = timer.getElapsed();
```

Comment: great solution! Thanks. Also I have recently learned that I can create a holder class(aka mutable Long) and use it directly in anonymous Runnable of CyclicBarrier